# how withdraw astar frontier tip reward with alice in dev mode, i use evm.withdraw(0x15fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde3, 1) report "bad Origin"

Tags: frontier, astar

[[image]]
https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar.git

./target/release/astar-collator --dev -d ./data -l info

astar frontier evm use HashedAddressMapping in evm pallet

alice public key is d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d

H160 is 0cf49bc5aca76015898fbdfc914af870bf057aeff1d347225b6c01595ad0699b = BlakeTwo256( b"evm:"[0..4] + 15fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde3 )

evm miner address is 5CMh6W6x5ZJaj2QGndYHa4Pc4ppvSFc9J66mBrxwteUkRe8p = ss58(0cf49bc5aca76015898fbdfc914af870bf057aeff1d347225b6c01595ad0699b)

```
impl pallet_evm::Config for Runtime {
    type AddressMapping = HashedAddressMapping<BlakeTwo256>;
}

pub struct FindAuthorTruncated<F>(PhantomData<F>);
impl<F: FindAuthor<u32>> FindAuthor<H160> for FindAuthorTruncated<F> {
    fn find_author<'a, I>(digests: I) -> Option<H160>
    where
        I: 'a + IntoIterator<Item = (ConsensusEngineId, &'a [u8])>,
    {
        if let Some(author_index) = F::find_author(digests) {
            let authority_id = Aura::authorities()[author_index as usize].clone();
            return Some(H160::from_slice(&authority_id.to_raw_vec()[4..24]));
        }
        None
    }
}

impl<H: Hasher<Out = H256>> AddressMapping<AccountId32> for HashedAddressMapping<H> {
    fn into_account_id(address: H160) -> AccountId32 {
        let mut data = [0u8; 24];
        data[0..4].copy_from_slice(b"evm:");
        data[4..24].copy_from_slice(&address[..]);
        let hash = H::hash(&data);

        AccountId32::from(Into::<[u8; 32]>::into(hash))
    }
}

fn pay_priority_fee(tip: Self::LiquidityInfo) {
        // Default Ethereum behaviour: issue the tip to the block author.
        if let Some(tip) = tip {
            let account_id = T::AddressMapping::into_account_id(<Pallet<T>>::find_author());
            let _ = C::deposit_into_existing(&account_id, tip_after_commission.peek());
        }
    }
```